# Show that $f(z)=az+b$ if $f$ is of the form $g(x)+h(y)$ and $f$ analytic

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, complex-numbers

Suppose that $f$ is analytic in a domain $\Omega$ and $f(z)=g(x)+h(y)$ for $z=x+iy \in \Omega$, where $g,h$ are complex-valued functions. Show that $f(z)=az+b$, where $a,b \in \mathbb{C}$ are constants.

**My Work So Far :**

Since $f(x,y)=u(x,y)+iv(x,y)$ is analytic on $\Omega$ we have

$$u_x=v_y \quad u_y=-v_x$$

Also

$$f(x,y)=g(x)+h(x)=u_0(x)+u_1(y)+i(v_0(x)+v_1(y))$$

I'm guessing. I'm not really sure where to go from here but Im thinking that our $f$ has to be the sum of $2$ analytic functions $g,h$. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Summarize to $f_x=u_x+iv_x$, $f_y=u_y+iv_y$ so that $f_y=if_x$.
From $f(z)=g(x)+h(y)$ we have $f_x(z)=g'(x)$ and $f_y(z)=h'(y)$. We conclude $h'(y)=ig'(x)$. The left side does not depend on $x$, the right does not depend on $y$, hence both sides must be constant, hence $g,h$ linear in $x$ resp. $y$.

Answer (score 2):

**HINT:** decompose $g$ and $h$ in their real and imaginary parts and apply C-R equations.